# Setting attributes of an EditText added dynamically in Android

Tags: android, layout, attributes, android-edittext

I am developping an android app which downloads an xml and displays a layout with a number of edittexts, checkboxes, spinners, etc. added dynamically like this:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
EditText nameField = new EditText(this);
ll.addView(nameField);
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
sv.addView(ll);
setContentView(sv);
```

I'm having trouble with setting some properties to an EditText added this way. For examle android:maxLength attribute can easily be set in an xml layout but I found no method to do the same in the java code.

How can I do it when hawing to add dynamically?

Thanks,
Zoltán from Hungary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the XML attributes in the docs, it lists the corresponding method you can call in your java [code for each attribute](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

So for example setting the `maxLength` attribute can be accomplished through the `setFilters(InputFilter)` method.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I really could have figured it out :)