# Android/java - trouble creating newlines with TextView

Tags: java, android, text, newline

I just want to append a TextView element to my linearlayout in order to add a newline to the screen the users see on the phone. I tried:

```
final TextView newline = new TextView(this);
newline.setText("\n"); 
main_layout.addView(newline);
```

... but to no avail. In fact this code made my phone vibrate angrily for some reason.

Help much appreciated!

EDIT - typo removed, and main_layout is my linearlayout element to which I'm appending content (strings).

Comment: Where does the title_response variable come from? Whence cometh the variable main_layout? And as I see it you never set the content of the text view

Comment: was a typo, now fixed, thanks

Comment: Please post the declaration and definition of the variable main_layout.

Comment: sure:

main_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.main_layout); 

It's the one thing in my XML file that I want to append content to, and currently I have no troubles appending regular text there.

Comment: And all this happens in the onCreate method or where?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie myself, so maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but shouldn't your code read:

```
 newline.setText("\n");
```

Or you could just do:

```
textView.append("\n");
```

to append a /n to an existing TextView element

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the TextView to your layout with the add() function. Better practice is to create a layout xml file for your view. It is much easier to work with.

Comment: I want to dynamically add content to the screen from a JSON variable I'm getting, hence why I'm trying to do stuff in Java. 

Also, I tried using add() and got:

"The method add(String) is undefined for the type TextView"

Comment: The method i mean is addView. Be sure to add the edittext to the view you are using. This topic is covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205775/setting-attributes-of-an-edittext-added-dynamically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

And how is newLine getting '\n' text if you setting it on title_response?

And angry buzzing usually indicates that your application crashed. Welcome to the club :)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing to the ctor of the TextView an AttributeSet as second parameter, setting the "lines" attribute. Just in order to make sure that the TextView is not created as "signle-line",